# What is the best way to call my API in WASM?

Tags: webassembly, uno-platform

I am trying to get a connection to my API.
I am using SwaggerClient to make a call to it, but when I do, I get the **System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Property AutomaticDecompression is not supported.** 
So what is the best way to make a call to my API so it works on WASM?

Comment: I can just use the  var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); without the   AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate and get to the API but the whole application freezes after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumption of web-services (assuming http/json) in the Uno Platform works just the same as any .NET application. Use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

I'm not familiar with SwaggerClient but I'm assuming there's a HttpClient under the hood.

For WebAssembly you'll need to create a WasmHttpHandler and then pass it in as the innerHandler of HttpClient.

```cs
#if __WASM__
            var innerHandler = new Uno.UI.Wasm.WasmHttpHandler();
#else
            var innerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#endif
            _httpClient = new HttpClient(innerHandler);
```

See https://github.com/unoplatform/uado for an example using HttpClient.

Comment: I added the code and it gave me a response 200 but I got an ApiException: Could not deserialize the response body stream in the console. Do I need to deserialize it in some way that works for WASM?( this all works on UWP)

Comment: I was able to get the connection just using normal HttpClient. Thank you.